# Instantiable anonymous Java Intefrace:Is it possible or am I wrong?

Tags: java, interface, anonymous-class

In the Java7 API reference([Java API 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)) there's a function `list()` of `File` class that has the signature:

```java
public String[] list(FilenameFilter filter)
```

where *`FilenameFilter`* is an interface. Suppose the use of this function in a program is something like below:

```java
String[] list = new File(directory).list(new FilenameFilter() {

     @Override
     public boolean accept(File f, String s) 
     {
        return s.endsWith(".java"); 
     } 
});
```

As you can see we are instantiating an interface anonymously.

Please correct me if I'm wrong but is instantiating an interface valid in Java?

The reason I'm asking this because I thought interfaces are not instantiable(because interfaces don't have constructors) and for using an interface you have to implement that interface by a class. Then how's that possible that we are instantiating an interface without implementing by a class here?

Can anyone kindly help me find the error in my logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not instantiating an interface. You are instantiating an **anonymous class**, which  implements that interface.

Assuming, the code posted above is in the file `Foo.java`, then you will see the following output by the compiler:

1. `Foo.class`
2. `Foo$1.class`

where `Foo.class` is obviously the compiled `Foo` class and `Foo$1.class` is the compiled anonymous class which you used in the code.

You'll find the specifics in the [Java Language Specification, Chapter 15.9.5. Anonymous Class Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)